# How to import an EODData download link to a python variable

Tags: python, text-files, stock

I'm trying to import a text file of all of the NASDAQ symbols from EODData (http://eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NASDAQ) into a python variable to save as a csv file. When I put the link into a Chrome browser the file downloads, but when I try to import it using urllib2 or pandas it looks like it is reading a website.

It seems to be similar to: [EodData wsdl java connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283211/eoddata-wsdl-java-connection) but I'm trying to do it in python.

```py
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("http://eoddata.com/Data/symbollist.aspx?e=NASDAQ")
for line in data:
    print line
```

Comment: could the answer help your question?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you must log in in order to download the data. You can download your data on chrome because you are automatically logged in. but through python, you have to register/log in. Try to check out [the login API](https://eoddata-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/eoddata_client/eoddata_client.html#EodDataHttpClient.login) of the website and include your credentials in your code.

you have to look at the `__init__` methods to fill it out with your credentials :

```
def __init__(self, username, password,
             base_url='http://ws.eoddata.com/data.asmx/',
             max_login_retries=3, logger=None):
    """
    Args:
        username (str): Account username. 
        password (str): Account password.
        base_url (str): Base url of SOAP service 
            (defaults to `http://ws.eoddata.com/data.asmx/`).
        max_login_retries (int): Maximum login retries, increase if there 
            are several clients working in parallel.
        logger (logging.Logger): Client logger.
    """
    self._token = ''
    self._username = username
    self._password = password
    self._max_login_retries = max_login_retries
    self._base_url = base_url
    self.logger = logger or logging.getLogger('eoddata_client')
```

As per the documentation, you have to replace the username and password with your credentials. Also, you'll have to add the token which can be extracted from your account on the website.